# Printing all values in one line in python in stead of multiple columns

Tags: python, oracle

I have a python code that gathers values from from multiple sources of a database, the output looks something like this
[image: Output I am getting currently:]

However I want to tune this function that will display the values like:

[image: Output desired:]

Following is the function which has some inputs from the database and are parsed accordingly:

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import fileinput
import string
import os, xmlrpclib


#contraints
DESIREDCOUNT = 50000
YEARS = [number of years i specify]
PARAMHASH = ['val1', 'val2','val3','val4' ]

for year i YEARS
        ids = getYearlySamples(DataCURR, year)

        modVal = len(ids)/DESIREDCOUNT;
        modval = int(modVal)


        if modval == 0:
            modval = 1

        finalids = []
        count = 0
        for id in ids:

            count = count + 1
            if count % modval == 0:# or True:

                sampleId = gatSamples(DataCURR, id)
                # grab the passed Value
                score = getXXValue(DataCURR, id)
                colldt = gatDate(DataCURR, id)
                dsMap = gatSamples(DataCURR, id) # will take sampleId



                for sid in dsMap:
                    for ds in dsMap[sid]:
                            for mark in dsMap[sid][ds][1]:

                                line = "%s,%s,%s,%s"%(sid, mark, score, colldt)

                                for col in PARAMHASH:
                                    if col == 'Somevalue1' or col == 'somevalue2':
                                        try:
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][1][mark][col]['val']
                                        except:
                                            line = line + ",*"
                                    else:
                                        try:
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][1][marker][col]['val']
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][2][marker][col]['val']
                                        except:
                                            line = line + ",*"

                                print line
```

Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `,` after your print statement.

i.e. `print line,`

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import fileinput
import string
import os, xmlrpclib


#contraints
DESIREDCOUNT = 50000
YEARS = [number of years i specify]
PARAMHASH = ['val1', 'val2','val3','val4' ]

for year i YEARS
        ids = getYearlySamples(DataCURR, year)

        modVal = len(ids)/DESIREDCOUNT;
        modval = int(modVal)


        if modval == 0:
            modval = 1

        finalids = []
        count = 0
        for id in ids:

            count = count + 1
            if count % modval == 0:# or True:

                sampleId = gatSamples(DataCURR, id)
                # grab the passed Value
                score = getXXValue(DataCURR, id)
                colldt = gatDate(DataCURR, id)
                dsMap = gatSamples(DataCURR, id) # will take sampleId



                for sid in dsMap:
                    for ds in dsMap[sid]:
                            for mark in dsMap[sid][ds][1]:

                                line = "%s,%s,%s,%s"%(sid, mark, score, colldt)

                                for col in PARAMHASH:
                                    if col == 'Somevalue1' or col == 'somevalue2':
                                        try:
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][1][mark][col]['val']
                                        except:
                                            line = line + ",*"
                                    else:
                                        try:
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][1][marker][col]['val']
                                            line = line + "," + dsMap[sid][ds][2][marker][col]['val']
                                        except:
                                            line = line + ",*"

                                print line,
                    print
```

Comment: the comma after line only prints everything in one line, however if you check the second image, as soon as the number changes, I want to print it on a next line
Thanks

Comment: Added another print statement, so when you reach the end of the first for loop, it prints a newline

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Done. 
Thanks again